# How to train a model to categorize user browser history?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Part-1: How do we constitute serialized training data for model training? For instance, if I were creating a prediction model using visited web pages data, what's the best way to render such data?

Example from training data: [<website 1, website 2, website 3>, entertainment], where entertainment is one of the labels (Summarizing the category of the web pages that user browsed in the last session)

Part-2: Is RNN the best method to train on such data for classification?

Comment: Logically wouldn't you have one label for each website? Since a user may browse switching between different categories. If yes that would a task of [sequence labelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_labeling), usually done with [CRFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field)

Comment: in general sequence labelling means classifying every instance in the sequence, assuming that the order of the sequence plays a role. Classifying the whole sequence (one label for the full sequence) would be a different task and I don't know what is used for that.